# 404 error page displayed when I redirecting to views through Laravel middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware

I am creating app which is contain 3 user roles which are **admin**, **clerk** and  **patient**.
When I use middleware and when I login it displays the `404 not found` error. And, when I get the 404 page, the URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home`
I am new to laravel and I can not find where my mistake is..

**User Model:**

```
public function Patient(){
        if($this->role == 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function Clerk(){
        if($this->role == 1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function Admin(){
        if($this->role == 2){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**constants.php**

```
define('ADMIN',2);
define('CLERK',1);
define('PATIENT',0);

return [
    'ADMIN' => 2,
    'CLERK' => 1,
    'PATIENT' => 0,
];
```

**LoginController.php**

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo;
    
    public function redirectTo()
    {
        switch(Auth::user()->role){
            case 0:
            $this->redirectTo = '/patient';
            return $this->redirectTo;
                break;
            case 1:
                $this->redirectTo = '/clerk';
                return $this->redirectTo;
                break;
            case 2:
                $this->redirectTo = '/admin';
                return $this->redirectTo;
                break;
            default:
                $this->redirectTo = '/login';
                return $this->redirectTo;
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeController.php**

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

**Admin Middleware**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Admin
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }

        if (Auth::user()->role == 0) {
            return redirect()->route('patient');
        }

        if (Auth::user()->role == 1) {
            return redirect()->route('clerk');
        }

        if (Auth::user()->Admin()) {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
}
```

**Clerk Middleware**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Clerk
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }

        if (Auth::user()->role == 0) {
            return redirect()->route('patient');
        }

        if (Auth::user()->Clerk()) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        if (Auth::user()->role == 2) {
            return redirect()->route('admin');
        }
    }
}
```

**Pateint Middleware**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Patient
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }

        if (Auth::user()->Patient()) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        if (Auth::user()->role == 1) {
            return redirect()->route('clerk');
        }

        if (Auth::user()->role == 2) {
            return redirect()->route('admin');
        }
    }
}
```

**Web.php route**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/patient', [PatientController::class, 'index'])->middleware('patient')->name('patient');
Route::get('/clerk', [ClerkController::class, 'index'])->middleware('clerk')->name('clerk');
Route::get('/admin', [AdminController::class, 'index'])->middleware('admin')->name('admin');

// Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

I am requesting you to check & notice me what to do.
Thank you very much !
Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php`

Replace this

```
public const HOME = '/home';
```

to

```
public const HOME = '/';
```

Comment: I changed, then all three users are redirected only into the `patient` dashboard even clerk & admin.  @JS TECH